# Can I hide browser require window, when I do not fill input?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, require

I want to make modern form and I have animated inputs which should  be required, because if I remove require, the animation will not work so I want to remove the usual browser window which is showing when I do not fill input.
[image: Require window which I want to hide.]

Can i hide it?
If yes, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`novalidate`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) attribute:

```
<form novalidate>
[...]
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, It works but the website reloads and I do not want reload so do you know what can i do?

Comment: Ok, thank you I already know how not to reload form.